Nothing is displayed after NPM Run Build and Firebase Deploy
When I deploy to firebase this is what I get in the logs and the main.css and main.js can't be found. Nothing displays in the webapp site
this is part of my index.html
title
script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.56adkfvef.js"
link href="/static/css/main.56adkfvef.css" rel="stylesheet"
it has numbers (56adkfvef for example) here and what do they correspond? Is it from .next/static? after building the next js app?
enter image description here
The app will be deployed. Already performed npm run build and firebase deploy
Google Cloud Console Query Logs:
Error: Could not find a production build in the workspace.next directory. Try building your app with 'next build before starting the production server
Headers:
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error (from disk cache)
